# setting a default property in maven3. Possible?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

Is it possible to set a default property in maven3. I can fetch the CATALINA_HOME from bash by following

```
 <properties>
     <cargo.tomcat.home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</cargo.tomcat.home>   
 </properties>
```

But if the variable is not set and I run the evaluate expression command I get null object

! mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=cargo.tomcat.home

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate (default-cli) @ cargo-selenium-springmvc-webapp ---
[INFO] No artifact parameter specified, using 'com.keybroker.spike:cargo-selenium-springmvc-webapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT' as project.
[INFO] 
null object or invalid expression
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.721s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 17 16:51:48 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would be interested in setting a default $CATALINA_HOME. I don't mind using another plugin but vanilla maven3 would be best. So what i am looking for

```
if $CATALINA_HOME is set by bash then use it
otherwise if the is a -DcatalinaHome argument passed to maven, then use that 
if all else fails, default to XYZ path for $CATALINA_HOME
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I have tested this on Windows 7 and Maven 3.0.4. `FOO` is my example environment variable.

First, add the following profile to the POM

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>env.FOO</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>!env.FOO</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <env.FOO>default_FOO</env.FOO>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

As you already know, the placeholder `${env.FOO}` is used elsewhere in the POM which will be replaced with a real value. The three ways to supply a value are:

**1)** By setting an environment variable

```
set FOO=env_FOO       (Windows)
export FOO=env_FOO    (Bash)
```

**2)** Supplying a command line parameter (this will override the environment variable)

```
mvn -Denv.FOO=cmdline_FOO    (note the env. prefix)
```

which will override the environment value.

**3)** Not setting `FOO` by any of the previous methods, the value in the POM will be activated clause, by the `!env.FOO` and be set to `default_FOO`

Comment: If I would like to set 10 variables, how it'll work?

Comment: With multiple `<profile>` elements and multiple command line overrides `-Denv.FOO=cmdline_FOO -Denv.BAR=cmdline_BAR`

Comment: Unmaintable @andyb... But ok, I understood the approach.

Comment: This answer is quite old now, so a newer version of Maven might have solved this or a plugin might exist to manage this better. Are you on the latest version?

Comment: Yes... Maven doesn't know how to handle this... I posted my doubt on "The Java Specialists" community on Slack, and they said to me to migrate to Gradle (confirming my theory). I'm on Gradle now...